# Java String Array max min unique occurrence

Tags: java, arrays, string, unique, instances

My input is a n number of strings . I want to get the unique values , as well as number of occurance of these string case insensitive.

I have a thought of getting the input in array ; sort it and do loops to calculate the occurance. Is there  any other way?

Comment: How does your input (<i>n number of strings</i>) look like? Is it an array, a list or a map? Or anything else?

Comment: Map strings to numbers of occurrences.

Comment: it is an array of strings

Comment: book;glass;phone;watch;mobile;ink;pen;watch;glass;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Stream api facilities to get what you want:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("hello","world","Hola","Mundo","hello", "world","Hola","Mundo","mundo","Hello","Hola","mundo","Mundo");

Map<String, Long> ocurrences = list
        .stream()
        .map(String::toLowerCase) // make case insensitive
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println(ocurrences);
```

Output:

> {world=2, mundo=5, hello=3, hola=3}

Answer (score 1):

```
public Map<String, Integer> calculateOccurences(Collection<String> collectionOfStrings) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (String string : collectionOfStrings) {
            String stringAsLowerCase = string.toLowerCase();
            Integer integer = map.get(stringAsLowerCase);
            if (integer == null) { //this has never been added
                map.put(stringAsLowerCase, 1);
            } else {
                map.put(stringAsLowerCase, integer + 1);
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
```

This will return a map where the keys are the unique words and each value will tell you how many times it appeared.

Comment: Use `Integer integer = map.getOrDefault(stringAsLowerCase, 0);` then you can get rid of the conditional logic